# How to recursively add tier to objects in an array PHP

Tags: php, recursion, php-7

I have a bunch of objects tiered in an array, and want to recursively loop through them with PHP to add their corresponding tiers.  How can I do that?

NOTE: The structure of the array could go much deeper than shown.

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object //should be tier 1
        (
            [name] => Object name
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object //should be tier 2
                        (
                            [name] => Object name
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => stdClass Object //should be tier 3
                                        (
                                            [name] => Object name
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                )
                                        )
                                    [1] => stdClass Object //should be tier 3
                                        (
                                            [name] => Object name
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                )
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                    [1] => stdClass Object //should be tier 2
                        (
                            [name] => Object name
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => stdClass Object //should be tier 3
                                        (
                                            [name] => Object name
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                )
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
    [1] => stdClass Object //should be tier 1
        (
            [name] => Object name
            [children] => Array
                (
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where specifically are you having difficulty. Post your code.

Comment: I relented on requiring OP to post their own effort, because I was bored and wanted to see how easy it would be to do.

Comment: @fubar I was stuck on this all day.  I tried several iterations of failed attempts, so it seemed counterproductive to pick one example at random to pick apart.  Your solution seems to work via your jsfiddle...  I appreciate your time and hope it works out!

Comment: Super!  It works.  Thanks for the help.  I marked your answer as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is actually quite straight forward.

You need to iterate over each level of the structure, setting the tier, and when you encounter a node with children, recursively call the same function, but increment the tier value.

I used `json_decode` to more easily create the `stdClass` objects for the example, which you can see working here: https://3v4l.org/oCJUV

```
<?php

function setTier(array $nodes, $tier = 1)
{
    return array_map(function ($node) use ($tier) {
        $node->tier = $tier;
        $node->children = setTier($node->children, $tier + 1);

        return $node;
    }, $nodes);
}

$structure = json_decode('
    [{
        "name": "a",
        "children": [{
            "name": "c",
            "children": [{
                "name": "e",
                "children": [{
                    "name": "g",
                    "children": []
                }]
            }, {
                "name": "f",
                "children": []
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "d",
            "children": [{
                "name": "h",
                "children": []
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "b",
        "children": []
    }]
');

$structure = setTier($structure);

print_r($structure); die;
```